# Is "I wonder if I could get a full refund if I want to." correct?

Tags: grammar

I would like to come in to get an exchange.
I wonder if I could get a full refund if I want to.
or
I wonder if I could get a full refund if I want.

I don't know the difference between "I want to" and "I want" when I use it at the end of the sentence.
What situation I can speak "I want to" or "I want" to each other?
Would you give me some examples or situations?

Answer (score 1):

We take short cuts in speech all the time.

So, the statement:

> You can go if you want to go.

is generally shortened to:

> You can go if you want to.

and even to:

> You can go if you want.

People understand all three versions to mean exactly the same thing.

While the third version is both common and acceptable in informal speech, I would keep the preposition for formal or written exchanges, if only because it sounds better, at least in your example.

Alternatively, you could replace **want** with **wish** or **desire** which are now generally (but not necessarily) used in this context without the preposition. That's to say, it's become idiomatic to drop it.